# How Cross entropy loss works with label and not a one hot?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, loss-function

In the pytorch [toturial](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html) when it comes to calcualting loss it seems it just uses class labels and not a one hot encodeing. How this is calcuated?

[image]